# HardDrive-to-HDTV Playback, Site Recommendation

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm seeking options about getting an HDTV to play videos that I store on a hard drive. What Stack Exchange site (if any) is appropriate for configuration and device tech specifications of video-to-HDTV type questions?

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) has an [hdtv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hdtv) tag. You could also check [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @SebastianSimon careful about video.se. Their on-topic states *Note that questions about home theater systems are not production related and thus not on topic*